# Media Element Js video player doesn't play correctly

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

Good morning,

I try work with mediaelementjs video player.
My html:

```
<video id="player" width="758px" height="400px"  controls="controls" autoplay preload="auto">
     <source type="video/flv" src="media/demo.flv" />
</video>
```

Javascript:

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer("#player",{
     success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {

                        // call the play method
                        mediaElement.play();

                    }
             });
```

I obtain this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'pauseMedia'
mejs.PluginMediaElement.pausemediaelement-and-player.min.js:28
mejs.MediaElementPlayer.pausemediaelement-and-player.min.js:94
mejs.MediaElementPlayer.meReadymediaelement-and-player.min.js:85
mejs.PluginMediaElement.dispatchEventmediaelement-and-player.min.js:32
mejs.MediaPluginBridge.fireEventmediaelement-and-player.min.js:34
(anonymous function)
```

What's wrong?

Can you help me please?

Seems it call this:

```
pause: function () {
    if (this.pluginApi != null) {
        if (this.pluginType == 'youtube') {
            this.pluginApi.pauseVideo();
        } else {
            this.pluginApi.pauseMedia();
        }           


        this.paused = true;
    }
},
```

**Update**
I try:

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer("#player");
player.play();
```

I dont' obtain error but it doesn't play.

Comment: can you provide the script where `pauseMedia` is in

Comment: pause: function () {
  if (this.pluginApi != null) {
   if (this.pluginType == 'youtube') {
    this.pluginApi.pauseVideo();
   } else {
    this.pluginApi.pauseMedia();
   }   
   
   
   this.paused = true;
  }
 },

Answer (score 1):

I`m using this:

```
//Global player
var Player = {};

    var videoDiv = document.getElementById('videoDiv');

    if(url.search("youtube") >= 0){
        videoDiv.innerHTML = '<video width="480" height="270" id="videoPlayer"><source type="video/youtube" src="'+url+'" /></video>';

    }else{
        videoDiv.innerHTML = '<video width="480" height="270" id="videoPlayer" src="'+url+'" />';

    }

    $('video').mediaelementplayer({
        success: function(media, node, playerElement) {

            Player = playerElement.media;

            //console.log('mode: ' + media.pluginType);

            Player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function( event ) {

                if(Player.paused) return;

                Editor.setTime(Math.round(Player.currentTime));

            });
            Player.addEventListener("seeked", function( event ) {

                Editor.setTime(Math.round(Player.currentTime));

            }); 
            Player.addEventListener("progress", function( event ) {

                if(Player.paused) return;

                console.log('currentTime '+Player.currentTime);
                console.log('progress '+Player.buffered.length);
                var count = Player.buffered.length;
                for(i=0;i<count;i++){

                    console.log('start ',Player.buffered.start(i),'end ',Player.buffered.end(i));

                }

            }); 
            Player.addEventListener("load", function( event ) {

                console.log(event);

            }); 
            Player.addEventListener("error", function( event ) {

                console.log(event);

            }); 
            Player.addEventListener("playing", function( event ) {

                console.log(event);

            }); 
            Player.addEventListener("canplay", function( event ) {

                console.log(event);

            }); 
            Player.addEventListener("loadeddata", function( event ) {

                console.log(event);

            }); 
        }
    });


// You can access the Player obj outside the function scope, because it is global
// But only after the player has been loaded!
```

HTML:

```
<div id="videoDiv" style="width: 360px; height: 300px;" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer("#player");
player.play();
```

or this:

```
new MediaElement('player', {
  success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {

  },false);
 mediaElement.play();
});
```

Comment: I have try second mode that you have describe and I obtain this error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null
mejs.HtmlMediaElementShim.createmediaelement-and-player.js:795
mejs.MediaElementmediaelement-and-player.js:786

Comment: add # `new MediaElement('#player', {`

Comment: I have try var player = new MediaElementPlayer("#player");
player.play(); I dont' obtain error but it doesn't play.

Answer (score 0):

As for what I can tell from a far I think that the MediaElementPlayer needs a mediaElement.pause();

I've found this from mediaElementjs.com:

> ```
> <script>
> // JavaScript object for later use
> var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player',/* Options */);
> // ... more code ...
> player.pause();
> player.setSrc('mynewfile.mp4');
> player.play();
> </script>
> ```

Maybe try to set the pause(); and see what errors it gives.